# How to make Windows executable file from cpp code written under Ubuntu with OpenCV library?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling

I wrote cpp code using OpenCV library, compiled it with cmake and everything works good on Ubuntu. Now I need to compile the same code for Windows 7 or higher. I have no experience with cross compiling, is there any at least relatively easy and reliable way how to do it? Probably somehow change the CMakeLists or so?
Building OpenCV library for Windows seems according official tutorial pretty demanding.

Comment: What about using [pre-built Windows binaries](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html)?

Comment: if you already done that on ubuntu - what's to be afraid of ? it's pretty much the same receipe.

Comment: Do you need cross-compilation? The usual route is to compile the Windows code on Windows, using the Visual C++ compiler. Cross-compilation in this case means compiling _for_ Windows _on_ Linux.